# uploading symbols to appcenter for flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-app-center

As per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/android-ndk), one can upload symbols for android app to app-center using below command

```
 appcenter crashes upload-symbols --breakpad {symbols file}
```

The symbol files would be located at `obj/local/$ABI/`

But where to find or how to generate/upload debug symbols for flutter apps?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @AR I want to upload debug symbols to app-center, so that I get more information about a crash

Comment: Flutter is not officially supported by App Center.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is not yet supported by App Center.

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/#get-started for the list of supported platforms by App Center.